# React-Router how to prevent from redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, routes, react-router

So I have a problem in my code that when I refresh my page it sends me a NotFound page, but when I don't refresh the page still works while changing the route (single page application)

My routes code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navigation from './src/containers/Navigation/Navigation';
import PageProjects from './src/containers/PageProjects/PageProjects';
import NewPost from './src/components/pages/Projects/NewPost/NewPost'

import Home from './src/components/pages/Home/Home';
import Calendar from './src/components/pages/Calendar/Calendar';
import Team from './src/components/pages/Team/Team';
import Settings from './src/components/pages/Settings/Settings';
import NotFound from './src/components/pages/NotFound/NotFound';



class App extends Component {


  render() {

return (

  <div className="App" style={{ height: '100%' }}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/projects" component={PageProjects} exact />
          <Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar} exact />
          <Route path="/team" component={Team} exact />
          <Route path="/newpost" component={NewPost} exact />
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} exact />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} exact />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Only my "/profile" page works because it's the page that I'm sending the index.html file from my route server

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__basedir + "/react/index.html");
});
```

My Navigation Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Toolbar from '../../components/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import SideBar from '../../components/SideBar/SideBar';
import Backdrop from '../../components/Backdrop/Backdrop';

import Home from '../../components/pages/Home/Home';
import Calendar from '../../components/pages/Calendar/Calendar';
import Team from '../../components/pages/Team/Team';
import Settings from '../../components/pages/Settings/Settings';
import NotFound from '../../components/pages/NotFound/NotFound';


class Navigation extends Component {
      state = {
    sideBarOpen: false,
  }

  barToggleClickHandler = () => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return{sideBarOpen: !prevState.sideBarOpen};
    });
  };

  backdropClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({sideBarOpen: false});
  };

  render() {
let backdrop;

if(this.state.sideBarOpen){    
  backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler}/>;
}

return (

    <section className="Navigation">
    <Toolbar barClickHandler={this.barToggleClickHandler} />
    <SideBar show={this.state.sideBarOpen}/>
    {backdrop}
    <main style={{marginTop: '150px'}}>
    </main>
  </section> 

    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

What can I do?
Thanks
(I'm using Reactjs, Nodejs, Express..)

Comment: What are steps to reproduce?

Comment: can you please show your `Navigation` Component?

Comment: @RaghavGarg done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__basedir + "/react/index.html");
});
```

or use hashrouter

```
<HashRouter>
    <div>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/profile" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/projects" component={PageProjects} exact />
      <Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar} exact />
      <Route path="/team" component={Team} exact />
      <Route path="/newpost" component={NewPost} exact />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} exact />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} exact />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: Only one thing, the route shows a hash now, how can I remove it?

Comment: That's what it means by hashrouter, If you don't want hash you have to use the first option that I have posted with BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick !

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__basedir + "/react/index.html");
});
```